# Possible ng2-inline issues with md-options

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app that uses ng-inline v1.1.0. Recently, I am getting a syntax error:

> Unexpected closing tag "md-select". It may happen when the tag has
>   already been closed by another tag...

My team and I looked through the HTML thoroughly and can see that all the tags are closed. However, when looking at the inlined html it is obvious what the issue is. We can see that the md-option tag within the select is not closed, hence the error.

> `<md-select><md-option *ngFor="let test of tests" [value]="test">{{test}}</md-select>`

As you can see, the option tag is not closed though it is closed in the HTML.

In the template it looks like this:

```
 <md-option *ngFor="let test of tests" [value]="test">{{test}}</md-option>
```

Has anyone run into this or have any ideas? We are all very stumped.

Comment: Where is `md-option` closed? Where should Angular put the `test` value? It' unlikely that `{{}}` will work with self-closed tags.

Comment: It isnt. It just continues on and then when it hits another md-select the md-option tag is again not closed.

Comment: md-option is a tag that closes. <md-option *ngFor="let test of tests" [value]="test">{{test}}</md-option>

Comment: Check out https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#inside-ngfor for how Angular processes ngFor. You should  have closing md-option tag in your template markup.

Comment: Or, use the version with `<ng-template>` instead.

Comment: As I showed, in our template it IS closed. Its after it is inlined that it seems to bomb.

Comment: Oh, it was a comment. I suggest you edit your question to illustrate this. Does not this still work? Can you create a plunk to illustrate the issue?